# Child overflow visible on small screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries, overflow

[Overflow Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VspYF.png)

```css
section {height: 100vh;background: #00f}
h1 {font-size: 150px;text-transform: uppercase;background: #f00}
```

```html
 
<section><div><h1>i am creative web designer</h1></div></section>
```

The problem is in the small screen the parent section is stopped fill the screen and the child H1 is overflow it like the picture. I don't know why?

Comment: What is the behavior you are expecting?

Comment: I expect that the parent is containing all the child element.

Comment: Your font is too big for the parent to contain

Comment: Can you check this template [Template with problem](https://moamen-ragab.github.io/html-css-javascript-temp-001/) when I try to resize it to a small size the same issue appear but the font size does not solve the issue

Comment: Make it small size and scroll to the right you will find a white space and this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add `position:absolute` to your section part and for each element inside you could add `position: relative`.

```css
section {
  position:absolute;
  /* height: 100vh; */
  background: #00f;
  height: auto; /*This will make the height change depending on the element inside*/
}

h1 {
  posiiton:relative;
  font-size: 150px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #f0
  }
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <h1>i am creative web designer</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word-break: break-all;
```

```css
section {height: 100vh;background: #00f}
h1 {font-size: 150px;text-transform: uppercase;background: #f00; word-break: break-all;}
```

```html
 
<section><div><h1>i am creative web designer</h1></div></section>
```